# Ansible Inventory based on a own Database

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I tried researching for a better solution than having a ansible inventory file.
My idea is to have a solution where I can pull my inventory information out of a Inventory database.

I haven't found any usefull approaches yet and I'd be really interested in proposals.

regards and thanks

Comment: For an entry point: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html

Comment: Thanks for hint. 
Now I'll have to specify my question in a more precise direction. Has anyone experiences with using a postgres database as an Ansible Inventory

Comment: SO is a specific site. If you want to have some quality time here, you should get familiar with the way it works. More specifically, questions should be precise enough to be answered and comments are not meant for chating nor asking questions. You can read (far from exhaustive list) [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask), [Create a minimal complete verifiable example](/help/mcve), [How comments work](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), [SO code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), [How much effort is expected from SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/9401096)...